# PlaySound Gives Windows Error Sound ,Not Sound I Need

Tags: c++, audio, mp3, playsound

I Wanted To Make A Simple Piano Using C++. I Will Check If User Pressed A Key On Keyboard And Play The Piano Sound. Key Sounds Are Downloaded On Desktop And They Are .mp3 Files. So Just For Test I Wrote This Code :

```
#include "MyTestCodes.h"
//MyTestCodes.h Includes
/*
#include <iostream> //Input/Output Stream For Console
#include <string>   //For String
#include <fstream>  //File Stream 
#include <vector>   //Changable Index Structure
#include <Windows.h>//For System Commands
#include <algorithm>//Easy Sorting For Arrays/Vectors ...
#include <iomanip>  //For Outputting With Given Precision
#include <cmath>    //Easy Math Functions
#include <stdio.h>  //Standard Input/Output For Given Types
#include <conio.h>  //For Getting Key Presses
#include <ctime>    //For Getting Real Time
#include <filesystem>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h>
#include <mciapi.h>
*/

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PlaySound("C:/Users/niko/Desktop/key01 F.mp3", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    // Tried With "\\" Too 
}
```

I Also Tried Without `MyTestCodes.h` And Include Other Libraries And Header Files By Myself (I Wrote `MyTestCodes.h` By Myself Too). I Mostly Included Those :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h> 
#include <Mmsystem.h>
#include <mciapi.h>
```

Comment: Note that the dup states that Windows does not support MP3 playback. Also, capitalising every letter of sentences makes them more difficult to read, so please avoid that in future.

Comment: @KenY-N My Code Does Not Give Error. It Compiles Succesfully, But Does Not Play Sound I Need

Comment: You Need To Read The Entire Answer In The Duplicate Question, Including The Bit About MP3s, Which Is Also In The Advice @KenY-N Gave You. I Am Writing This Way In Case You Cannot Read Sentences That Use Correct Capitalization.

Comment: Yes, because it is a run-time error - `PlaySound()` should return `FALSE` if you try to play a file format it doesn't support, so please check the return value.

Comment: @KenY-N On 'cout << PlaySound("C:\\Users\\niko\\Desktop\\key01 F.mp3", NULL, SND_FILENAME);' It Gave Me 1, Means It Is True, File Format Is Supported, But Still Gives Error Sound

Comment: Presumably these files are really short and just contain a single note? You'd be much better off using uncompressed WAV files, due to the overheads of the MP3 file format they probably aren't even much smaller than the WAVs

Comment: PlaySound can't play MP3 files. Only WAV files. The WAV file can be PCM or encoded with a compression to use a codec at runtime.  I believe you can use a tool such as ffmpeg to convert MP3 into a compressed WAV file. But if you just want a simple solution, make your WAV file with uncompressed PCM bytes.

Comment: Thanks For Help Everyone.  I Turned It To .wav, And Worked. Have A Nice Day

Comment: please don't edit answers into the question. @selbie what was wrong with the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is the problem, but here is an idea: try converting mp3 to wav

For some reason WinMM doesn't like .mp3 files, and only accepts .wav

I hope this solves it